# Is May’s deal still on the table?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, procedure

These last weeks have been a firework of Brexit news in the UK and among others led to at least [one politician (Michael Gove) admitting he would vote for May’s deal if it returned to parliament](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/politics/2019/09/05/michael-gove-says-would-vote-theresa-mays-brexit-deal-returned/) (I believe I heard a few people voice it in one of the Commons debates I heard, but my memory is foggy and I certainly wouldn’t know who it would have been).

Disregarding any potential future deals the current Prime Minister may or may not secure and assuming normal operations when Parliament returns from prorogation next month could either of the following theoretically happen:

1. An MP or a group of MPs introduce a bill or motion or whatever to overturn Parliament’s previous decision (if necessary) and accept the deal Theresa May agreed with the EU; or
2. In case the [Kinnock amendment has actually passed and is consequential](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/live/2019/sep/04/brexit-crisis-boris-johnson-mps-bill-blocking-no-deal-eu-no-deal-parliament-politics-live?page=with:block-5d701f298f08b2e15bc1a6fc) (I’m not sure I understood the procedures and contents entirely), May’s deal is returned to parliament as a result of the procedures of legislation and a majority accepts the deal.

Both cases would lead to the UK exiting the EU under the terms of May’s deal; if there are others that I am missing please don’t feel required to ignore them.

In short: **Could the House of Commons still decide to vote on May’s deal and agree to leave the EU under that deal’s terms?**

Pre-emptive note: I am not asking whether any of these procedures are likely to happen or who would support them, merely if they are theoretically and legally possible and not disqualified by precedent or customs.

Comment: It's the only deal there is, so yes. IMO the MPs will vote on it and pass it (or some oh so slight variation to work around legal barriers if any; for instance by reverting to the original, Northern Ireland only backstop) at the last minute, if the EU blocks a new extension and MPs fail to repeal article 50.

Comment: The Lords [called](https://www.theneweuropean.co.uk/top-stories/kinnock-amendment-kept-in-lords-1-6257011) the amendment '"confusingly drafted" and "legally inoperable".' But apparently left it in place because removing it would require another commons vote for which there was no time due to the upcoming prorogation.

Comment: For the EU it is the *only* deal on the table. *And* the UK has agreed to this when it requested the current extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Commons can vote on pretty much anything, including May's deal. The EU has already agreed to it and has not signalled that it wishes to retract that agreement.